# Use of undeclared identifier 'a' in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I keep getting an error saying "use of undeclared identifier 'a' ". To my knowledge, I have declared 'a' equal to 0 so it should be set.

```
int numOfBits(short num)
{
    for(int a = 0; num; num >> 1){
        a += num & 1;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Declare 'a' outside for loop

Comment: learn about the variable scoped and visibility

Answer (score 7):

It's out of scope.

```
int numOfBits(short num)
{
    // Requires C99 for loop variable declaration
    for(int a = 0; num; num >> 1) {   // `a` declared *inside* the
                                      // for loop block scope
        a += num & 1;
    }
    return a;                         // `a` is no longer in scope
}
```

Just move the declaration out:

```
int numOfBits(short num)
{
    int a;
    for(a = 0; num; num >> 1) {
        a += num & 1;
    }
    return a;
}
```